# Sublime Text, auto fix "Missing semicolon"

Tags: sublimetext3, eslint

I am using eslint in my project.

And is it possible that to make sublime text to auto fix the missing semicolon error?

Is there any package can do that?

Looking up the missing semicolon line and insert a `:` after the statement

Answer (score 3):

To do it in Sublime Text you can use the ESLint-Formatter plugin: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ESLint-Formatter

Or you can use the --fix command line parameter to automatically fix issues like this. Documentation is here https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#fix

There's a feature request open on GitHub for support in SublimeLinter for the --fix parameter https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint/issues/104
But it doesn't seem to be getting any traction since it's open from November 2015...

Documentation for this semi rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi

One other option is to use JSCS, find more info on how to use it here: https://medium.com/@addyosmani/auto-formatting-javascript-code-style-fe0f98a923b8

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript specification describes a feature called [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion), which is widely regarded as something you don't want to use. Most prominently, it has been expressed in Douglas Crockford‘s book *JavaScript: The Good Parts* in the chapter “Awful Parts”.

In short, there are cases in which automatic semicolon insertion leads undesired results, making your code behaving differently than intended (e.g. when returning an object.) This is where linters come in, they are meant to warn you about missing semicolons, but ultimately it's you who can decide how your code should behave.

For some in-depth information, [this article](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/) describes the problem pretty well.

However, you can *manually* append a semicolon using the [AppendSemiColon](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AppendSemiColon) package.